# Rect UITableViewCell in iOS 8 when beginupdate and endupdate

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

I'm building a `UITableView` with style tableview Grouped, and i give a gap (margin left) on method frame `UITableViewCell` like this

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    if(IOS_7){ //above ios 6
     CGFloat gap = 10.0f;

     frame.origin.x += gap;
     frame.size.width -= gap*2;
    }
    [super setFrame:frame];
}
```

the [result like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/em6AA.png).

and then after 5s, i did call method

```
[_table beginUpdates];
[_table endUpdates];
```

the result [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ou25h.png).

the gap on the right twice from my gap = (gap*2)

this problem only on ios 8,

is the iOS 8 call twice setFrame in uitableviewcell ?
and how to solve it ?

note:
- i have been tried with reset frame with `CGRectMake(0.0f, frame.origin.y, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, frame.size.height);` but if i'm using with ipad with left menu side, it's not solve my problem,
- does not use custom cell (just using default uitableviewcell)

Comment: Is it your full setFrame method?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the frame wrong. You should be doing this:

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    if(IOS_7){ //above ios 6
     CGFloat gap = 10.0f;

     frame.origin.x += gap;
     frame.size.width -= gap*2;
     [super setFrame: frame];
    }

}
```

Comment: sorry, i have been correction in method setFrame, before content method like [super setFrame:defaultFrame] become [super setFrame: frame],

Comment: @sawijaya > Can you add your full uitableviewcell class?

Comment: my uitableviewcell class same like default of uitableviewcell, i only add method setFrame and calculate in this method(setFrame).